# Изменение цвета объекта через интервал

Tags: delphi

Как сделать смену цвета ( желтый, голубой, белый ) объекта каждые 5 секунд?
shape, label

Comment: shape,label,timer

Comment: вы про плавный переход ? или просто смена цвета ?

Comment: Смена цвета

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот неплохой вариант:

```
var counter:integer = 0;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
inc(i);
case i of
   1:shape1.Brush.Color:=rgb(255,255,0);
   2:shape1.Brush.Color:=rgb(0,190,255);
   3:begin shape1.Brush.Color:=rgb(255,255,255); i:=0;end;
end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Shape1: TShape;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
   i: integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
 const
 color: array [1..3] of tcolor = (
   clYellow,
   clBlue,
   clWhite
   );
begin
 if i=3 then
   begin
  i:=1;
   end
  else
   begin
  i:=i+1;
  end ;
 Shape1.Brush.Color:=color[i];
end;

end.
```

Comment: Ужас! Зачем так длинно?

Comment: Массив-то как раз хорошо. Клампится в диапазон Low(color)..High(color) несколько неуклюже, это да.